# How to get command prompt output? Why can't I get it in this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

I try to get string in command prompt by the way using "subprocess". The execution contents is to read "TOC" of CD-DA.I'm using "cdparanoia".
In case of keyin on command prompt I can get "TOC".

```
import subprocess
class Aaa():
    def __init__(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen("cd-paranoia",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out = p.communicate()[0]
        str = out.decode(encode="utf-8")
        print(str)
Aaa()
```

In the above code, it's displayed red string of "TOC" pressing reset button on interactive window in Visual Studio 2017. But it can't be stored in variable "str". 
What should I do?

Comment: probably requires redirection from stderr: `stderr=subprocess.stdout` and `out` is a tuple (output,error) BTW. Please provide error message.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks your advice! I solved it soon inserting "stderr=subprocess.STDOUT".  "out" is a tupple but there is no error before inserting "stderr". Thanks!

Comment: oh I hadn't seen the `[0]`, correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes can choose to output to output or error streams. In your case you're not redirecting the error stream. You can for instance merge both output & error streams like this:

```
    p = subprocess.Popen("cd-paranoia",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

and the rest of your code does the job.